# Facebook API: create event using Facebook's form

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've done my searching for the answer to this but it remains unclear.  This could be a simple "possible" or "not possible" answer.

I have a site I'm creating that uses Facebook Connect (may or may not be relevant).  I would like users to be able to create Facebook events based on events posted on this site.  I'm familiar with the Facebook API and realize I could make my own form that would allows users to create a Facebook event... but I don't really think I want to do that work.

Is there a way I can point a user to Facebook's "create event" form but simply pre-populate some of the fields to help them along?

For example, say I wrote post about a free concert and had a button that said "make this an event on Facebook!".  I would like that to link back to the fB event form with a title "Reggae Night 2010" and then from there the user could go on and create the event as they normally would.  I don't see the point in doing my own form, validation, etc.

Thanks!

Comment: @Ryan... are you still around?  Did this ever answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, obviously have a FB login enabled page and/or when the click your site's "click here to create event in Facebook" button, then have it check for whether the user is already logged into FB.  Then use javascript to prepopulate the fields on the form on this page...

http://www.facebook.com/events/create.php

...with the info from your site's event.

That should be it!
-Flak

EDIT:  spankmaster79 - yes, that's what I said above.... have your code CHECK for WHETHER you're ALREADY LOGGED INTO FB *first*. (Please remove the -1, I'd appreciate it)

Comment: @spankmaster79 - yes, that's what I said above.... have your code CHECK for WHETHER you're ALREADY LOGGED INTO FB first. (Please remove the -1, I'd appreciate it)